# Subscription in Stripe Payment .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

[image: Screenshot]

I want a Subscription in Stripe, which the recurring payment facility will be enabled according to the plan created in stripe dashboard. From Dashboard I get a plan id  How could I achieve tagging the customer with the plan Id

```
<form action="/Stripe/Charge" method="POST">
    <article>
        <label>Amount: $5.00<br/>
               Buy   </label>
    </article>
    <script src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
            class="stripe-button"


            data-key="pk_test_...."
            data-locale="auto"
            data-description="Sample Charge"
            data-amount="500">
    </script>

    <article>
        <label>Amount: $29.00 <br/>
            Pro Subscription 
               </label>
    </article>
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_..."

        data-description="Pro Subscription ($29 per month)"
        data-panel-label="Subscribe"
        data-label="Subscribe"
        data-amount="2900">
    </script>


</form>
```

am I on the correct path? I want to make both subscription and single payment page 
my doubt is tagging the planId according to users selected plan

Comment: i am using stripe for payment gateway   i cant tag since i  don,t have enough   reputation

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET

Comment: If you are looking for the latest solution, check out https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you following the [ASP.NET MVC tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/aspnet) in the Stripe Docs? If not, it’ll help a lot. Have a read before reading the rest of my answer.

In [Step 2](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/aspnet#step-2-create-aspnet-controller) you create a controller which charges the customer. It’s in that same block that you’d want to [subscribe the customer to your plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet#create_subscription). It should end up looking like this:

```
public IActionResult Charge(string  stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
{
    var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
    var charges = new StripeChargeService();
    var subscriptions = new StripeSubscriptionService();

    var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions {
      Email = stripeEmail,
      SourceToken = stripeToken
    });

    var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions {
      Amount = 500,
      Description = "Sample Charge",
      Currency = "usd",
      CustomerId = customer.Id
    });

    var subscription = subscriptions.Create(customer.id, new StripeSubscriptionCreateOptions() {
      PlanId = "your-plan-here"
    };

    return View();
}
```

Without changing any more code from the tutorial, this will subscribe a customer to the plan `your-plan-here` as well as charge them $5. This is because all logic is handled in the back-end, the `data-amount` in the Stripe checkout is only used to display to the user the amount they will be paying.

Personally when having a charge and a subscription I’ll set the `data-amount` to be the sum of the charge and the first month of the subscription, or I’ll just use a [custom form](https://stripe.com/elements). But it’s up to you to decide what your customers will prefer.

---

### How does Stripe work?

A typical Stripe payment goes as follows:

1. The user inputs their card details into the Stripe form
2. Upon submitting the form, Stripe creates a token which is sent to your server, along with some other information outlined [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout)
3. When the server receives the token the server must use the token and email to create a “Stripe customer.”
   The token “SourceToken” or “source” becomes the customers payment method
4. The server can then charge the customers account by creating a “charge”, subscribe a customer to a plan by creating a “subscription” as well as a bunch of other things.

In the case of the example above, `var customer = customers.Create(...)` creates Stripe customer and assigns it to the variable `customer`. `charges.Create(...)` issues a charge to a customer and `subscriptions.Create(...)` subscribes a customer to a plan that you’ve created in the Stripe dashboard.

Comment: Thank you @Bennett , bro can you please explain what is really happening here What do  **subscriptions.Create()** , **customers.Create()**  **charges.Create()** function do , Do they communicate with stripe when ever these function calls , Or there is something more i have to do , I am doing this for 1st time and i dont have any idea once again thank you for your help

Comment: Yeah those functions communicate with Stripe from your server. I’ve updated the answer with a bit more information about how a transaction is typically processed using Stripe.

Comment: i have a doubt like if i have 1 One time submission and 2 different subscriptions how to function **charge()**  behaves

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this before but you don’t need to issue a charge to create a subscription. Also after you attach a “SourceToken” to a customer, you can create as many charges or subscriptions as you want, all from one subscription. The front end is more for the users convenience, it doesn’t control the amount of the transaction or anything at all. It’s just a way to create a “SourceToken” which can be used as payment.

Comment: my doubt is like i dont have any plan for 1 time payment   in that case how do the function charge()  works since it contains  subscriptions.Create(...) Do i have any way to tell function charge that what kind of payment this customer is selected ( like a one time or subscription) @Bennett

Comment: Well if you don’t have any reason to make a once off payment, just delete everything relating to the charge and only have the code which creates a subscription. When you create a subscription Stripe handles creating the charges for you.

Comment: i have both and different subscription plans how function charge() understands which planId to select    am i getting it in the wrong way @bennett

Comment: Sorry I think I understand now. You’d have to implement your own cart or some kind of system for that, using sessions or some other method. When the user adds an item to the cart it would be sent back to the server and stored in a session. When the checkout is processed the Charge() function would check to see what’s in the cart and then create the relevant subscriptions. It’s out of the scope of the tutorial however, and requires some advanced knowledge of .net

Comment: Not acutally , All i have is 3 type of payment submit buttons. all i need is to recognizance  which method customer selected

Comment: I just added an image pay with card is wont have any subscription its a one time payment option Other button will be have a subscription  how to understand what customer choose  Map customer according to that @Bennett

Comment: You could make a second method Subscribe() in the HomeController which handles the subscription. But if you do that you’d need the second button to be in a second form that has method=“/Home/Subscribe”

Comment: Stripe Payment Integration in Asp.net Web Forms and its 100 percent  working code and you can also download application 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Implement-Stripe-Payment-Gateway-In-ASPNET